# How to optimize object writing performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, object

If there were 2 objects like this:

```
let obj1 = { foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo' };
let obj2 = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' };
```

And I wanted to change the value for obj2's key called foo to be some other value like `some other value`.

What would be the most performant way to do this?

```
obj2.foo = 'some other value';
```

or

```
obj2 = { ...obj2, foo: 'some other value'};
```

Comment: `obj2.foo = 'some other value';` is faster. The second has the additional overhead of cloning `obj2`

Comment: Performance aside, the second way will also break any references to `obj2` since you're replacing it with a new object.

Comment: Well they're doing very different things. Which one do you want - change the property of the object, or create a new object and change the variable?

Comment: Why did you expect having better performance by using complicated code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct assignment is faster than others. The last approach involves - creating a new object from the properties extended from old object and overrides the property values, which involves more operation compared to other approaches.
https://jsperf.com/obj-perf1122

[image: object assignment performance]

Comment: On my machine (Firefox on macOS), the difference is even more extreme. My test went over 1.1 billion for the first two and about 7.5 million for the third.

Answer (score 0):

The second way you describe is much slower. By using the spread syntax, you're copying over each property of `obj2` into a new object and then modifying (overriding) one of the properties. If you think about `obj2` having many, many properties or storing a lot of information, this will be costly.

In the first way, saying `obj2.foo = 'some other value'`, all that has to happen internally is to take the address in memory of `obj2`, jump to some offset where `foo` is located, and change what that memory contains.